# Unable to fetch session Id from ServiceBusQueueTrigger

Tags: java, azure-servicebus-queues

Unable to fetch session Id from ServiceBusQueueTrigger in JAVA .
It is throwing error

```
@FunctionName("function")
public void run(
@ServiceBusQueueTrigger(name = "msg",
                         queueName = "myqueuename",
                         connection = "myconnname",
                          isSessionsEnabled = true,) String message,
                @BindingName("CorrelationId") UUID correlationId,
                @BindingName("SessionId") String sessionId,
 final ExecutionContext context ) {
 context.getLogger().info(message);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the error?

Comment: Exception: NullPointerException: 
Stack: java.lang.NullPointerException
[2022-09-02T04:54:25.308Z]  at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.BindingDataStore.getTriggerMetatDataByName(BindingDataStore.java:66)
[2022-09-02T04:54:25.308Z]  at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.ParameterResolver.resolve(ParameterResolver.java:62)